# Effectiveness of Abdominal Vacuum

Tags: exercise, muscle, abdominals

How effective is the [Abdominal Vacuum](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/TransverseAbdominus/AbdominalVacuum.html)? I like the exercise because I can do it anywhere, sitting on a chair, walking, sitting in bus, but I don't feel any pain like I do in other muscles after exercise, so I am skeptical if it has any benefit at all. Does anyone get any gain from this?

Why does this exercise not cause pain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on personal experience it will not improve the appearance of your core much, but it does help stabilize your core (increase strength of Transversus Abdominus) which improves your lifts and overall balance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking a strict abdominal vacuum, it exercises the *transversus abdominis* (TA) and pretty much nothing else. As an isometric exercise, the load is limited, but it is present. There will not be any real muscle build-up, but it may help stabilize your abdomen.